# Django template label_suffix

Tags: django, django-templates

I am trying to extract the `label_suffix` in Django template.

The term `label_suffix` is defined [here in docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/forms/fields/#label-suffix):

I have tried:

```
{{ field.label_suffix }}
{{ field.label_tag.label_suffix }}
```

where field is the fields of my Django form class.

Nothing seems to work. There is no error, it doesn't print anything. Is there a way to extract the suffix in the template?

If I do `{{ field.label_tag }}` it prints the form label with suffix but I just wanted to extract the suffix.

Comment: Is there an error? What output do you get? What do you think `field` is; where is it being defined?

Comment: No there is no error, If I do {{ field.label_tag }} it prints the form label with suffix but I just wanted to extract the suffix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
{{ field.label_tag|cut:field.label }}
```

Comment: Perfect! That Works! Thank you! :D